# Polymorphic relationship and querying conundrum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a DB for a logistics system

It consists of 3 main models: `Users`, `Requests` and `Carriers`.

`Request` gets created by a `User` and later a `Request` gets assigned to a `Carrier`.

Important: There's a twist - `User` and `Carrier` form a PA

Here's the Schema:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :requests
    belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true
end
```

Note: `User` table contains the PA columns `meta_id` and `meta_type`

As mentioned above `Carrier` is a special type of user who represents the employees who can be associated to a requests to carry it out - to transport it.

```
class Carrier < ApplicationRecord
  # Carrier is a Type of User
  has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
  
  # I guess what I need is something like has_many: :assigned_requests through ???
end
```

And finally, the `Requests` that are created by the User and later get associated with the carrier

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  # Relevant attributes and FK's for the clarity of the question:
  # assigned_carrier_id      :integer
  # user_id :integer
  # Foreign Keys
  # fk_rails_...  (assigned_carrier_id => users.id)
  # fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)

  belongs_to :user # User who created the request  
  belongs_to :assigned_carrier, class_name: "User" # Carrier who got assigned to request
end
```

This schema and active record methods allow me to easily retrieve all requests created by a user like this:

`user.requests` or `user.requests.active`

Nevertheless, what I'd like to be able to do is add methods to the Carrier model to do something like this:

`carrier.assigned_requests` OR `carrier.assigned_requests.some_scope`

What do I have to add to my `Carrier` and `Request` model to achieve this behaviour?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution - kind of:

Within the User model I added:

```
has_many :assigned_requests, 
foreign_key: "assigned_carrier_id", 
class_name: "Request"
```

And now I can do this:

`carrier.user.assigned_requests`

Now, what I'd like to achieve is this:

`carrier.assigned_requests`

Comment: Your question is lack of migration or schema for these tables. Do you have assigned_carrier_id in `requests` table?

Comment: Sorry @ruslan-k, yes there's assigned_carrier_id attrib. in the request model. I'll add the table attributes into my original question.